# Get custom post fields and display them

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field

I am using the [wpfacet](https://facetwp.com) plugin.

I have two custom fields:

[image]

I am trying to display these by the following code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

         <span class="main"><?php $key_values = get_post_custom_values("Gear",get_the_ID()); ?></span>
         <span class="main"><?php $key_values = get_post_custom_values("Size",get_the_ID()); ?></span>

   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

However nothing gets displayed.

I also tried the following and still get the same result

`<?php get_post_custom_values("Gear",get_the_ID()); ?>`

Kind regards!

Comment: You aren't `echo`ing anything but are just saving information to a variable. This is a PHP problem and has nothing to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_post_custom_values()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values) is meant for retrieving fields that have multiple entries.

> ### Description
>
> This function is useful if you wish to access a custom field that
>   is not unique, i.e. has more than 1 value associated with it.
>   Otherwise, you might wish to look at get_post_meta().
>
> Returns an array containing all
>   the values of the custom fields with a particular key ($key)
>   of a post with ID $post_id (defaults to the current post if
>   unspecified).

Using it the way you are...

... isn't going to work because you will get an array. That is in addition to the PHP syntax issue that you are not actually `echo`ing anything.

You need to be using [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) instead, and `echo` the result:

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post(); ?>
  <span class="main"><?php echo get_post_meta("Gear",get_the_ID(),true); ?></span>
  <span class="main"><?php echo get_post_meta("Size",get_the_ID(),true); ?></span>
}
```

Honestly, while not strictly WordPress, you are probably going to be better off with slightly more complicated code:

```
$span = '<span class="main">$s</span>';
while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post(); 
  $gear = get_post_meta("Gear",get_the_ID(),true);
  if (!empty($gear)) {
    sprintf($span,$gear);
  }
  $size = get_post_meta("Size",get_the_ID(),true);
  if (!empty($size)) {
    sprintf($span,$size);
  }
}
```